# Stable diffusion models in WL?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks

Are there any diffusion-based `(text + image) -> image` generation models available in Mathematica, Wolfram Repositories, or from third parties?

In particular, I'm looking for any stable-diffusion based models, not the original latent-diffusion. These neural nets (which are vastly superior to GANs) for image generation are now very mainstream: DALLE-2, Imagen, Midjourney, etc.

Here's a recently open-sourced diffusion model: https://stability.ai/blog/stable-diffusion-public-release

If it's possible to train or fine-tune that would be nice, but just inference with these models as `NetGraph` objects would be enough to poke at and play with them.

**References:**

- https://thealgorithmicbridge.substack.com/p/stable-diffusion-is-the-most-important
- https://arxiv.org/abs/2105.05233
- https://www.infoq.com/news/2022/09/stable-diffusion-image-gen/
- https://medium.com/mlearning-ai/the-gan-is-dead-long-live-the-dall-e-2-5a7e4d847179

Comment: Please find it here for the diffusion part:https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/269181/diffusion-probabilistic-model-in-deep-generative-modeling. The difference between what is posted and stable diffusion, is that stable diffusion applies a VQ-GAN for data preprocessing, which is currently not available.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Stable Diffusion-v1 is in the WNNR(https://resources.wolframcloud.com/NeuralNetRepository/resources/Stable-Diffusion-V1/).

Comment: A wrapper for this is also available on the Function Repository https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/StableDiffusionSynthesize/